# Mapper is not using another mapper, how to use a mapper from another mapper?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am experimenting with MapStruct where I want to have a mapper use another mapper to combine multiple objects into one. For my tests I have three domain objects, `DomainObject1`, `DomainObject2` and `DomainObject3`. I want to convert `DomainObject1` to a DTO, `TransferObjectA`, which has a field containing a second DTO, `TransferObjectB`, that is constructed using `DomainObject2` and `DomainObject3`.

I have two mappers, one that converts `DomainObject2` and `DomainObject3` to `TransferObjectB` which ignores a field in `DomainObject2` so it isn't converted:

```
@Mapper
public interface ObjectBMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "field1", ignore = true)
  TransferObjectB domainObject2ToTransferObjectB(DomainObject2 domainObject2, DomainObject3 domainObject3);
}
```

And a second mapper that converts `DomainObject1` to `TransferObjectA` which also accepts `DomainObject2` and `DomainObject3` so they can be converted using the above mapper and put on the resulting `TransferObjectA`:

```
@Mapper(uses = ObjectBMapper.class)
public interface ObjectAMapper {

  TransferObjectA domainObject1ToTransferObjectA(DomainObject1 domainObject1, DomainObject2 domainObject2, DomainObject3 domainObject3);
}
```

However, the `ObjectBMapper` doesn't seem to be used by the `ObjectAMapper` and the `field1` is converted (this results in an error because it is an `enum`). Why is the `ObjectBMapper` not used and how can I make sure that is will be used by `ObjectAMapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct currently can only use other mappers with a single source parameter.  There is an open feature request [mapstruct/mapstruct#2081](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2081) about this functionality.

What you could do is to use a wrapper object instead of multiple source parameters.